# MySQL COALESCE with two arguments?

Tags: mysql, coalesce

`COALESCE` is an SQL function that returns the first non-NULL expression among its arguments. So in the following statement...

```
SELECT USER.user_id, 
        USER.firstname, 
        USER.lastname, 
        ...
        COALESCE(EMPLOYEE.title, '') title, 
        ...
FROM USER
```

... it is basically saying that if `EMPLOYEE.title` is `NULL`, then return and use  `''` instead. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What part seems confusing? If param 1 is null, it'll return second param. If that's null, it'll return third param.....and so on. If every param is null, it returns  null.

Comment: It's okay now @AshwinNair. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say that `EMPLOYEE.title` equals `'CEO'`. If we plug this into the `COALESCE` function, our query would look something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE('CEO', '') sub_sector;
```

If we ran it, we would get `'CEO'`. Now let's say that `EMPLOYEE.title` is `NULL`. If we plug that into the `COALESCE` function, our query would look something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, '') sub_sector;
```

If we run that, we will get `''` since `COALESCE` returns the first non-null value in its argument list. Since the first value is `NULL`, it will then check the next value, `''`, which is not `NULL`, so it will return it.

In the case of your query, if the field `EMPLOYEE.title` has a `NULL` value, the `COALESCE` function will return `''`.